# Can all crossings in a graph be moved to one point?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-drawing

Consider a graph $G$ with at least two unavoidable crossings, say, the disjoint union of two copies of $K_5$. Can such a graph always be drawn so that there is only one singular point (where all crossings happen)? I guess there is an easy proof that this is not possible.

Comment: You might be interested in: Adams et al., "Knot projections with a single multi-crossing." *Journal of Knot Theory and Its Ramifications*, 24(03):1550011,
2015.

Comment: No, as Tony Huynh had said. The minimum number of crossing-points for a graph $G$ is its degenerate crossing number $\mathrm{dcr}\; G$. Schaefer (The Graph Crossing Number and its Variants: A Survey, Electronic Journal of Combinatorics (2014), #DS21), p.41 cites Pach & Tóth's claim that for $G=K_{5,5}$, $\mathrm{dcr}\; G\leqslant15$ but $\mathrm{cr}\; G=16$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No**, this is not always possible.

**Lemma.** Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex graph with at least $3n-2$ edges.  Then $G$ cannot be drawn in the plane so that all crossings occur at the same point.

*Proof.*  We make the standard assumption that every pair of edges which intersect in a drawing are not 'tangent' at the point of intersection.  Suppose $D$ is a drawing of $G$ where all edges cross at the same point.  Let $G'$ be the graph obtained from $D$ by introducing a new vertex at the crossing point and then suppressing all parallel edges. We claim that $|E(G')| \geq |E(G)|$.  Let $H$ be the subgraph of $G$ induced by the edges which pass through the crossing point.  Since no two crossing edges are tangent, $H$ contains at most one cycle (which must be a triangle).  Therefore, $H$ has average degree at most $2$.  It follows that $|E(G')| \geq |E(G)|$, as claimed.  Thus, $G'$ is a planar graph with $n+1$ vertices and at least $3n-2$ edges.  But this contradicts the fact that every $n$-vertex planar graph has at most $3n-6$ edges.

In particular, the above lemma implies that $K_7$ cannot be drawn so that all edges cross at the same point.

**Acknowledgement.** Many thanks to bof for help in making this answer converge to its present form (see the comments below).

Comment: I think the argument already works with $K_6$, which has crossing number 3. If all the crossings are at one point, then there's a planar graph with seven vertices and 18 edges, contradiction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it works with $K_6$.  You do not even need to know the crossing number of $K_6$ (only that it is at least $1$), since you get a planar graph with $7$ vertices and at least $16$ edges.  I just wanted to use a sufficiently dense graph, so that the contradiction is obvious.

Comment: I edited a $10$ into a $6$ accordingly though.  Thanks.

Comment: @bof You're right.  Thanks.  But after suppressing parallel edges, there will still be at least one new edge.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @bof There is an implicit assumption in graph drawing that if two edges intersect, then they are not 'tangent' to each other at the point of intersection. That is, edges must actually 'cross' if they intersect.  I think this rules out your drawing of $K_6$.

Comment: Of course, there is also another implicit assumption in graph drawing that no three edges cross at the same point (but that would not make sense for this question).  So, the answer to this question is 'yes' if you allow edges to touch (as in your construction), and 'no' if you insist that edges actually cross if they intersect.

Comment: My previous try was faulty because some edges touched without crossing, but now I believe i have a correct drawing of $K_6$ with $15$ crossings all at one point. Let ABCDEF be a regular hexagon with center O. Draw the $6$ sides and $3$ diameters as straight line segments. Draw the edges AC, CE, EA as semicircles outside the hexagon. Draw the edges BD, DF, FB as circle arcs passing through O.

Comment: @bof, well done! The 7-vertex graph you get by making the crossing point a vertex is a multigraph, with three edges from each of $B,D,F$ to $O$. So instead of $16$ edges, there are just $15$.

Comment: @bof Thanks for the perseverence!  I agree that your example works for $K_6$.  I don't think it works for $K_7$ though.  I will update my answer (again)!

Comment: shouldn't it also be a rule that two edges with a common endpoint should not cross each other? That would of course disqualify my $K_6$  example.

Comment: No, this is actually not a rule, and many researchers (including Tutte) have ignored crossings between incident edges at their peril.  The confusion stems from what the actual definition of crossing number is.  If you define the crossing number as the minimum number of pairs of edges which cross (this is sometimes called the pair crossing number), then the local move to get rid of crossings between incident edges can actually increase the pair crossing number.  See the survey of Marcus Schaefer mentioned by Rosie F above.